# How do I turn off 'like' notifications on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, notifications

On Twitter - I don't want notifications whenever someone likes my tweet, or likes tweets that I'm mentioned in.

However, I do want to be notified when someone replies to my tweets.

I want these settings to apply for what is known as the 'notifications timeline' in Twitter's terminology, ie notifications within the desktop browser application.

Is this possible to set up?

Comment: And as of today I just wanted to turn them back on to be able to stalk people who liked my amazing posts... :-( Seem to be hardcoded off now.

Answer (score 7):

One can just use the [Tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/) client:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: +1 yes this should work; use “a third-party app” was part of Option 1 in my answer; and it's good to see a concrete example. :-)

Comment: Does this still work from tweet deck? Could you send a specific link or instructions on how to get here?

Comment: @BryanShalloway: You use the settings functionality at the top of the notification column. Then you can filter by notification type and uncheck the Likes type.

Answer (score 6):

Native Twitter does not have this functionality. They used to, but not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**Disable "Liked" notifications for Web and Browser**

1. Log in to https://twitter.com/.
2. Navigate to [Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/) and select [Web notifications](https://twitter.com/settings/web_notifications).
3. Clear the check box for **Someone likes my Tweets**.
4. Click **Save changes**.

NOTE: Although the same can be done for notifications on [mobile devices](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169887), there is no way to filter the [Notifications timeline](https://twitter.com/i/notifications) that specifically. You can only filter *words* or *accounts* from your Notifications timeline, according to the Twitter help page [About the Notifications timeline (subheading Can I filter the notifications I receive?)](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169398)

Comment: Ok great. There's one little bug there. When you first go to Web Notifications there's a message that say's 'Turn on [Web notifications]' which is for getting browser notifications. You click that then press block, then you have access to these settings.

Comment: @user1068446 Thanks! Adjusted answer as noted.

Comment: Oh hey - this look slike it doesn't work. I think the web notifciations are just for browser/desktop notificaitons only. Not the notifications within the application itself.

Comment: @user1068446 Ah sorry, didn't realize you meant the Notifications timeline. It doesn't seem like you can be that specific with the notification timeline, according to the Twitter help page [About the Notifications timeline (subheading Can I filter the notifications I receive?)](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169398). Adjusted answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has a bunch of notification methods. The twitter.com website has settings for email notifications and for “web notifications” (browser notifications). This page: [How to See Twitter Notifications For Mentions, But Not Likes or Retweets (September 2017)](https://www.howtogeek.com/325854/how-to-see-twitter-notifications-for-mentions-but-not-likes-or-retweets/) has a bunch of methods that are relevant for Twitter's mobile app (iOS or Android), for the twitter.com website, and for other third-party Twitter apps.

However, none of these apply to https://twitter.com/i/notifications (called the “notifications timeline”) that the question here is about. For example, https://twitter.com/settings/web_notifications says:

> [image: these settings don't change the thing we care about]

and the official [help page](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/understanding-the-notifications-timeline) about the notifications timeline doesn't say anything about such filtering either.

So at this point, one's options, if one wants to avoid notifications for likes and retweets, are:

1. Don't consume notifications from https://twitter.com/i/notifications at all: use email notifications, or a third-party app, and just ignore (or hide) that tab on twitter.com, or
2. Use an in-browser method to hide these notifications.

I've been trying (2), and this is what I have so far (will update the answer as I make more progress). Type the following into the javascript console:

```
function hideBad() {
    for (let e of document.querySelectorAll([
        '.js-activity-retweet',           // "Retweeted your Tweet"
        '.js-activity-favorite',          // "liked your Tweet"
        '.js-activity-favorited_mention', // "liked a reply to you"
        '.js-activity-retweeted_mention', // "Retweeted a reply to you"
        '.js-activity-favorited_retweet', // "liked your Retweet"
        '.js-activity-follow',            // "followed you"
        '.js-activity-generic'            // someone liked something else…
        '.js-activity-retweeted_retweet'  // "Retweeted your Retweet"
    ].join(','))) {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

hideBad();
window.addEventListener('scroll', hideBad);
```

This will filter out notifications of those types, until the page is reloaded.

This seems to be working so far, so the next step would be to make it a bookmarklet, or a browser extension, or simply add relevant filters to whatever element-hiding extension you may be using. All of those would work; pick your favourite. For example, if you're using Adblock Plus, you can add the following to “My filter list”:

```
twitter.com##.js-activity-retweet
twitter.com##.js-activity-favorite
twitter.com##.js-activity-favorited_mention
twitter.com##.js-activity-retweeted_mention
twitter.com##.js-activity-favorited_retweet
twitter.com##.js-activity-follow
twitter.com##.js-activity-generic
twitter.com##.js-activity-retweeted_retweet
```

The main remaining problem is that the number shown next to the “Notifications” icon won't take these into account. One can probably live with that though. Of course, when twitter.com decides to change its CSS, all of this will break.